# Unable to run the XSLT through JAVA and Empty result observed in output

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I just want to fetch a piece of tags from XML file and I'm using it XSLT.

**XSLT:**

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/><xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/testng-results">
  <xsl:copy-of select="class/test-method[@status='PASS']"/>
  </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
    <class name="com.transfermoney.Transfer">
        <test-method status="PASS" name="setParameter" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
            <params>
                <param index="0">
                    <value>                   
                          <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                    </value>
                </param>
            </params>
            <reporter-output>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->
     </class>
     <class name="com.transfermoney.Transfer">
        <test-method status="FAIL" name="setSettlementFlag" is-config="true" duration-ms="5"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z">
            <reporter-output>
                <line>                                                             
                       <![CDATA[runSettlement Value Set :false]]>
                </line>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> setSettlementFlag
    </class> 
</testng-results>
```

**JAVA Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String XML = fetchDataFrmXML(".//Test//testng-results_2.xml");
        Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(".//Test//Cut.xslt")));
        t.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(XML)), new StreamResult(new File(".//Test//Sample1.xml")));
      }
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  <test-method status="PASS" name="setParameter" is-config="true" duration-ms="4" started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
   <params>
      <param index="0">
         <value>                   
          <![CDATA[runSettlement Value Set :false]]>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
   <reporter-output/>
</test-method>
```

**FetchXML:**

```
  public static String fetchDataFrmXML(String fileLocation) throws Exception 
  {
        file = new File(fileLocation);
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String temp;
        String result = "";
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result += temp;
        }

        br.close();
        return result;
  }
```

I'm getting the empty sample1.xml file after I ran the JAVA class file. But if the same XSLT script I just run it through online editor it's giving an expected result.

Is there any issue in my java file to execute the XSLT? please help me on this.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you've shown us. But you haven't shown us the method `fetchDataFrmXML()`; and of course we can't see what's in your filestore. The double slashes -"//"- in your file names look very odd to me, but I don't know if they're wrong. The CDATA tags won't be copied through to the output but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: What is the reason for using that method `fetchDataFrmXML` to read the file into a String? Why don't you simply use `new StreamSource(new File("foo/bar.xml"))` if you want to use a file as the input source to the XSLT transformation. It is also not clear whether your problem is in general to set up your Java code to run any XSLT correctly to read from and write to the file system or whether you think you have a problem with that particular XML and XSLT. Why are you using double slashes in the file paths with e.g. `Test//testng-results_2.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. The only things I changed were:

- declaring the variables used in your fetchDataFromXML() method
- Adding the missing space after version="1.0" in your stylesheet
- Changing the file names.

I added the line

```
System.err.println(t.getClass().getName());
```

to identify the XSLT engine used; the output was

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
```

You might like to do the same.

Looking more carefully at the output, it displays the record with status="PASS", which is what the code is selecting, though you said you wanted the one that has status="FAIL".

A note about your fetchDataFrmXML() method: it's incredibly inefficient to build up the content of a string by repeated string concatenation this way. Use a StringBuilder instead.

(I once earned myself $10K in consultancy fees by pointing this mistake out to a client, who probably saved themselves $1m in hardware costs as a result).